# Webpack, Angular2 and Bootstrap do not work together

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap-3, webpack

A simple import in `index.html` works. Why the extra hassle? How do I resolve the below?

I install in `package.json`

```
   "bootstrap":"3.3.7",
```

I am trying to load bootstrap

```
 import '../../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'


SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:76:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:528:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:565:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:473:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:432:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:424:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:483:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/Documents/frontend/-angular2/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css:6:4446)
    at Module._compile (module.js:556:32)
    at Object.exec (/Users/Documents/frontend/qangular2/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:94:6)
    at Object.module.exports (/Users/Documents/frontend/qta-angular2/node_modules/to-string-loader/src/to-string.js:6:54)
 @ ./src/app/app.component.ts 8:0-62
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/app/index.ts
 @ ./src/main.browser.ts
 @ multi main
```

Answer (score 0):

It should work with just doing

`import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"`
You may need proper loader. You can try

`{test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg|woff|woff2)$/,  loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000', }`

[Example](https://jorawarsingh@bitbucket.org/jorawarsingh/es6-bootstrap4.git)